# Loop invariant of linear search

Tags: algorithm, invariants, loop-invariant

As seen on Introduction to Algorithms (http://mitpress.mit.edu/algorithms), the exercise states the following:

**Input:** Array `A[1..n]` and a value `v`

**Output:** Index `i`, where `A[i] = v` or `NIL` if `v` does not found in `A`

> Write pseudocode for LINEAR-SEARCH,
>   which scans through the sequence,
>   looking for v. Using a loop invariant,
>   prove that your algorithm is correct.
>   (Make sure that your loop invariant
>   fulﬁlls the three necessary properties
>   – initialization, maintenance,
>   termination.)

I have no problem creating the algorithm, but what I don't get is how can I decide what's my loop invariant. I think I understood the concept of loop invariant, that is, a condition that is always true before the beginning of the loop, at the end/beginning of each iteration and still true when the loop ends. This is usually the goal, so for example, at [insertion sort](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/insertionSort.htm), iterating over `j`, starting at `j = 2`, the `A[1..j-1]` elements are always sorted. This makes sense to me. But for a linear search? I can't think of anything, it just sounds too simple to think of a loop invariant. Did I understand something wrong? I can only think of something obvious like (it's either NIL or between 0 and n). Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After you have looked at index `i`, and not found `v` yet, what can you say about `v` with regard to the part of the array before `i` and with regard to the part of the array after `i`?

Comment: v is not from 1 to i but could be after i, can this be a loop invariant?

Comment: ok, that wouldnt make sense... how about, v is not from [1...i], but this wouldn't be valid for the initialization of the loop, as i=1 and I cannot guarantee that v is not the first element. But I can't use negative bounds either, right?

Comment: Clash, take a look  at my answer below.

Comment: @Clash: Your first attempt does look sensible.  My hint would better be formulated as "Before you look at `A[i]` ...", so that the invariant holds at the _start_ of the loop.

Comment: for a new variable k < i, all the elements from A until index k are not v
But I still find it weird, as if i is 0, this would mean k=-1, which does not exist in A... is there a way to formulate this better? Or is it no problem, that k=-1? Can I then say, A[0...i-1] is not v? Even though it would be representing an impossible vector (for i=0)? Like A[0 ... -1]

Comment: @Clash:  Your exercise text seems to imply a 1-based array.  `i` then goes from `1` to `n`.  If you initialize `i` to `1`, then check `A[i]`, and finally increase `i`, your loop invariant holds for any array index smaller than `i`.  If there is no valid array index smaller than `i`, it trivially holds&mdash;anything is true for the empty set.

Comment: @Clash: that's not really a problem. Remember, this is pseudocode and math, not actual code on actual machines. If you assume the notation A[l...u] represents `{ A[i], ∀i i>=l ∧ i <= u }`, then A[0...-1] would represent an empty set. Saying that v is not on the empty set is true, so it holds at the beginning.

Comment: Great, that was my doubt. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 32):

```
LINEAR-SEARCH(A, ν)
1  for i = 1 to A.length
2      if A[i] == ν 
3          return i
4  return NIL
```

**Loop invariant:** at the start of the `i`th iteration of the `for` loop (lines 1–4),

```
∀ k ∈ [1, i) A[k] ≠ ν.
```

**Initialization:**

```
i == 1 ⟹ [1, i) == Ø ⟹ ∀ k ∈ Ø A[k] ≠ ν,
```

which is true, as any statement regarding the empty set is true (*vacuous truth*).

**Maintenance:** let's suppose the loop invariant is true at the start of the `i`th iteration of the `for` loop. If `A[i] == ν`, the current iteration is the final one (see the *termination* section), as line 3 is executed; otherwise, if `A[i] ≠ ν`, we have

```
∀ k ∈ [1, i) A[k] ≠ ν and A[i] ≠ ν ⟺ ∀ k ∈ [1, i+1) A[k] ≠ ν,
```

which means that the invariant loop will still be true at the start of the next iteration (the `i+1`th).

**Termination:** the `for` loop may end for two reasons:

1. `return i` (line 3), if `A[i] == ν`;
2. `i == A.length + 1` (last test of the `for` loop), in which case we are at the beginning of the `A.length + 1`th iteration, therefore the loop invariant is

   ```
   ∀ k ∈ [1, A.length + 1) A[k] ≠ ν ⟺ ∀ k ∈ [1, A.length] A[k] ≠ ν
   ```

   and the `NIL` value is returned (line 4).

In both cases, `LINEAR-SEARCH` ends as expected.

Comment: Beautiful! Mathematically precise and very well exposed. Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 8):

In the case of **linear search**, the loop variant will be the backing store used for saving the index(output) .

Lets name the backing store as **index** which is initially set to NIL.The loop variant should be in accordance with three conditions :

- Initialization : This condition holds true for index variable.since, it contains NIL which could be a result outcome and true before the first iteration.
- Maintenance : index will hold NIL until the item v is located. It is also true before the iteration and after the next iteration.As, it will be set inside the loop after comparison condition succeeds.
- Termination : index will contain NIL or the array index of the item v.

.

Answer (score 6):

Loop invariant would be

forevery 0 <= i < k, where k is the current value of the loop iteration variable, 
A[i] != v

On loop termination:

if A[k] == v, then the loop terminates and outputs k

if A[k] != v, and k + 1 == n (size of list) then loop terminates with value nil

Proof of Correctness: left as an exercise

Comment: Does this hold true for the initialization? 0 <= i < k would mean that i at the initialization is empty, null or something like that?

Comment: I can't prove it because I don't have your code. But, I would have an if-then-else statement inside my loop saying something like if A[i[ == v, return i. Then I could prove the initialization case for my code: k = 0. Either A[i] == v, in which case my loop terminatees and outputs k. Conversely, if A[i] != v, the for all 0 <= i <= 0, A[i] != v.

Comment: `0 <= i < k` holds for the initial iteration of the loop since you will get an empty array, which, in fact, does not include `v`, hence the condition is true _before the initial execution of the loop_.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have an array of length i, indexed from [0...i-1], and the algorithm is checking if v is present in this array.
I'm not totally sure, but I think, the loop invariant is as follows:
**If j is the index of v, then [0..j-1] will be an array that does not have v.**

Initialization : Before iterating from 0..i-1, the current array checked (none), does not consist of v.

Maintenance : On finding v at j, array from [0..j-1] will be an array without v.

Termination : As the loop terminates on finding v at j, [0..j-1] will be an array without j.

If the array itself does not have v, then j = i-1, and the above conditions will still hold true.

Answer (score 1):

The invariant for linear search is that every element before i is not equal to the search key. A reasonable invariant for binary search might be for a range [low, high), every element before low is less than the key and every element after high is greater or equal.
Note that there are a few variations of binary search with slightly different invariants and properties - this is the invariant for a "lower bound" binary search which returns the lowest index of any element equal to or greater than the key.

Source:https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/wvyvs/what_is_a_loop_invariant_for_linear_search/

Seems correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

The LS algorithm that I wrote is-

```
LINEARSEARCH(A, v)
  for i=0 to A.length-1
    if(A[i] == v)
      return i
  return NIL
```

I made my own assumptions for loop invariant for checking correctness of Linear Search:

1. At Initialisation- at i = 0, we are searching for v at i = 0.
2. At successive iterations- we are looking for v till i < A.length-1
3. At termination- i = A.length and till A.length we kept looking for v.